# Get rid of Xorg processes on Tesla card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, xorg, cuda

I am running a Workstation with two GPU boards. One older AMD board connected to my screens and a Tesla K80 for CUDA development. After installing Kubuntu 21.10 I have some problems like kernel launch timeouts and failed launches. Also I can not reset the K80 since two Xorg process are running. I use the K80 for CUDA only I think I do not need those processes.

I checked the drivers. In the “Additional Drivers” settings the newest available nvidia-driver-470 and **not** the Xorg Nouveau driver is installed.

I also found some “NVIDIA XServer settings” application in the K-Menu that lists my K80. I don’t know which package installed that application but anyway it seems to provide no relevant settings.

My questions:

1. Where do those Xorg processes come from?
2. Is there any sense in running these Xorg processes for a CUDA-only card?
3. How can I get rid of those processes permanently (or at least for a session)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found the answer to 3. There is a file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia.conf` on my system. I removed the content (by turning all lines into comments using `#`) and restarted the system. `nvidia-smi` does not show Xorg processes running anymore on the GPGPU.

Still no idea why the GPGPU was utilized by Xorg in the first place. Maybe it is a good idea to start a freshly installed system without the GPGPU plugged-in the very first time to avoid confusing GPU and GPGPU.